# How to set default selections for Plotly modeBar

Tags: angular, plotly.js

I am building an application in Angular 6 using Plotly.js for a scatter plot.

I need to set the default modeBar selection to "Show closest data on hover" (hoverClosestCartesian in documentation).

I am able to remove options from the modeBar, and have removed all that I do not want using the [config] option. As far as setting the active options, I do not know how to change that.

Some documentation can be found here ==> https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/modebar/buttons.js

```
    MyConfig = {
          scrollZoom: true,
          displayLogo: false,
          modeBarButtonsToRemove:['sendDataToCloud', 'select2d', 'lasso2d', 'hoverCompareCartesian', 'toggleSpikelines']
          };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `layout.hovermode = 'closest'` (https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-hovermode).